# Setting states for dynamic input fields in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, user-interface

I'm trying to dynamically generate input fields for the Rest response. I can't set an state by specifying an `unique Id` or `unique name` for all the input fields since the `name` and `id` values are generated dynamically.

Here's my code :

```
export default class Rest extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

            First_Name: "",
            data: [],
        }
    }
    handlesubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {First_Name} = this.state;
        console.log(this.state)
    }
    someFunc = (e) => {
        const state = this.state
        state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(state);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json').then((Response) => Response.json()).
                then((findresponse) =>
                {
                    console.log(findresponse.movies)
                    this.setState({
                        data: findresponse.movies
                    })
                })
    }
    render()
    {
        const {First_Name} = this.state;
        return(
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handlesubmit}>
                        <table className="tat"> 
                            <tr><th>name</th><th>year</th></tr> 
                            {
                    this.state.data.map((dynamicData) =>
                                <tr className="trow"> <td>  {dynamicData.title} 
                                    </td> <td> {dynamicData.releaseYear} </td>  <td><Input placeholder="First Name..." value={First_Name} name="First_Name" id={dynamicData.releaseYear} onChange={this.someFunc}/></td>
                                </tr>
                    ) }
                        </table>
                        <button type="Submit">submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                )
    }
}
```

[The output for the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44nWa.png)

The problem is that `e.target.name` specifies one particular name all the input fields generated. So If i'm setting `<input name={dynamicdata.releaseYear} />`, how will I set the state for all the input fields with dynamically generated names.

Thank you...

Comment: You need one `FirstName`  for each of your dynamic fields. Right now you are having only one.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to directly mutate your state:

```
someFunc = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);

}
```

You could do:

```
someFunc = (e) => {
    const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
    newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Updating:

changing `e.target.name` to `e.target.id`, so that each key `id` will store the value of the corresponding input field.

```
someFunc = (e) => {
    const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
    newState[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Comment: Yeah the function might work but when multiple input fields are rendered the name also should change so that each input values could be fetched uniquely. [e.target.name]points to the name of the input field and so I have to render multiple input names for the multiple input fields.

Comment: I have updated the answer. 2 things to note. 1) Do not change the state directly. 2) each input field needs to have a corresponding Key:Value pair inside state.

Comment: Changed as you said....Its not working.. I got stuck in it completely...

Comment: Are you able to `console.log(e.target.id)` inside `someFunc`?

Comment: Try changing `value={First_Name}` to `value={this.state[dynamicData.releaseYear]}` in `<td><Input placeholder="First Name..." value={First_Name} name="First_Name" id={dynamicData.releaseYear} onChange={this.someFunc}/></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i have faced this issue before. Update your `form` to

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.handlesubmit(e)}>
                        <table className="tat"> 
                            <tr><th>name</th><th>year</th></tr> 
                            {
                    this.state.data.map((dynamicData) =>
                                (<tr className="trow"> <td>  {dynamicData.title} 
                                    </td> <td> {dynamicData.releaseYear} </td>  <td><Input placeholder="First Name..." value={First_Name} name="First_Name" id={dynamicData.releaseYear} onChange={(e) => this.someFunc(e)}/></td>
                                </tr>)
                    ) }
                        </table>
                        <button type="Submit">submit</button>
  </form>
```

Change `onSubmit` and `onChange` functions to :

```
onSubmit={(e) => this.handlesubmit(e)}
```

and

```
onChange={(e) => this.someFunc(e)}
```

respectively.

The issue is because the scope of `this`, When you call the `onSubmit` or `onChange` your way,  `this` is the DOM element not the React component, hence `this` doesn't have access to React `state` properties.

**UPDATE:** based on your comments

Change the functions as below

```
onChange={e => this.someFunc(e, dynamicData.releaseYear)} // because dynamicData.releaseYear is the ID
```

Next

```
someFunc = (e, id) => {
        const state = this.state
        state[id] = e.target.value; // or state["prefix_"+id] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(state);
    }
```

OR if you want to use names

```
this.state.data.map((dynamicData, index) =>
                                (<tr className="trow"> <td>  {dynamicData.title} 
                                    </td> <td> {dynamicData.releaseYear} </td>  <td><Input placeholder="First Name..." value={First_Name} name="First_Name" id={dynamicData.releaseYear} onChange={e => this.someFunc(e, index)}/></td>
                                </tr>)
                    ) }

someFunc = (e, index) => {
            const state = this.state
            state[e.target.name +"_"+index] = e.target.value;
            this.setState(state);
        }
```

Comment: Actually the problem is not with the function. The function for handling the change and submit works just fine as they are.... What your telling I think it will work for a single input file but I'm trying to render multiple input fields for the number of times the rest function is called. So the problem is setting a name for the state since multiple input fields has different name.... @ Abhilash Nayak

Comment: Are the `e.target.name` and `e.target.value` are returning correct values?

Comment: Yeah it returns the correct values... The problem is that it takes the same input values for all the input fields rendered. I'll just post an image an update the question for a clear view.

Comment: How about now? using arguments